Rigged 2D characters not animated when rendering the scene
I have made those 2D puppets with grease pencil objects, and animated them. It works perfectly fine in 3D view. But when I start rendering the scene, some of the puppets appear in there T pose without any movement... while others are animated as they should be. I really don't know what I did wrong here, so I'd be so grateful if anyone can help me with this !
This is in 3D view

And this is when I try to render the animation... the guys on the left stay frozen in T pose while the one on the right moves correctly


Did you accidentally hide their Armature modifiers in render? The camera button over the modifier would be dark in that case.

Thank you for your awnser. No I checked that already, The camera buttons are all active !

Ho no in fact you were right sorry ! I just didn't know how to reach the armature modifier in the hierarchy ! Thank you so much !

Answered via comment: Did you accidentally hide their Armature modifiers in render? The camera button over the modifier would be dark in that case.
